# How to compare two variables/columns when one has much more measurements

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I'm working with the `Movielens dataset` and I would like to calculate the user engagement by giving ratings about different movies. The dataset looks like this (it has information about the users and the ratings they've given to different movies):

```
item_id              title release_date  video_release_date  \
0        1   Toy Story (1995)  01-Jan-1995                 NaN   
1        4  Get Shorty (1995)  01-Jan-1995                 NaN   

                                            imdb_url  unknown  Action  \
0  http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Toy%20Story%2...        0       0   
1  http://us.imdb.com/M/title-exact?Get%20Shorty%...        0       1   

   Adventure  Animation  Childrens  ...  Thriller  War  Western  user_id  \
0          0          1          1  ...         0    0        0      308   
1          0          0          0  ...         0    0        0      308   

   rating  timestamp  age  gender  occupation  zip_code  
0       4  887736532   60       M     retired     95076  
1       5  887737890   60       M     retired     95076
```

When calculating the user engagement I would like to compare which of the two genders engage more. Meaning do the female users give more ratings or the male ones give more ratings.

```
female_users = users.query("gender == ['F']")
female_users_ratings_count= female_users['rating'].count()
print('\nPercentage of female ratings:', round(((female_users_ratings_count/total_number_of_ratings)*100),2),'%')
print('\nPercentage of male ratings:', round(((male_users_ratings_count/total_number_of_ratings)*100),2),'%')
print('\nMale users give',  round((male_users_ratings_count/female_users_ratings_count),2), 'times more ratings.')
```

I count the number of ratings given by the female users and divide it by the total number of ratings, repeat the step for the male users and then calculate the ratio between the total number of ratings given by female users divided by the total number of ratings given by the male users.

However, the total number of male users is 3 times more than the female users.

```
print('\nTotal number of female users: ',total_female_users)
print('\nTotal number of male users: ',total_male_users)
```

Output:

```
Total number of female users:  273

Total number of male users:  670
```

How do I approach this problem of one of the genders having much more measurements in order to obtain the real number, representing the engagement of the two genders? Do I need normalization, standardization, rescaling, or something else?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question, but if you have more males giving more ratings than females, that is what you are going to get. Did you check that 273+670 is the actual number of ratings you find? Did you check for duplicates?

Comment: the idea was to calculate how much does the female user rate compared to the male user. Meaning which of the two genders engage more by giving ratings.

Comment: You got your answer in your code 273 females vs 670 males